# How to fix "could not find function" using parSapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to replace sapply by parSapply in my script in order to reduce the running time.

Here is the script that I am using with a dataframe example:

```
library(relaimpo) 

gene1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
gene2 <- c(3,1,2, 4) 
age <- c(20, 40, 60, 10) 
gender <- c("F", "M", "F", "F") 
datatest<- data.frame(gene1, gene2, age, gender) 

TEST<-sapply(datatest[,(1:2)], function(i) calc.relimp(lm(i ~ age+gender, data=datatest))$lmg) 


##until now it works; Here is when I replace sapply by parSapply: 

cl <- makeCluster(4) 
TEST2 <- parSapply(cl, datatest[,(1:2)], function(i) calc.relimp(lm(i ~ age+gender, data=datatest))$lmg)
```

I get this error message:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    2 nodes produced errors; first
>   error:could not find function"calc.relimp"

---

Would someone know how to fix this? 
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Best,

Bérengère

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the required objects in your cluster. Something like

```
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c('calc.relimp'))  # add other objects needed
```

should do the trick.